# Optional dynamic parameter in Crystal Report

Tags: sql, crystal-reports

I am creating a report with Dynamic parameters on CR.

All the parameters should be optional, as if the end user haven't select any parameter, then it will act like this parameter didn't exist at all.

After some searching I found the `.HasValue()` function, and after using it the report shows no data at all, so maybe I am missing something here.

Here is the original formula I have

```
{Command.Invoice Date} in {?Date} to {?To Date} and
{Command.SeriesName} = {?Department} and
{Command.DocNum} = {?DOCUMENT NO} and
{Command.SlpName} = {?Sales Emploee}
```

What is the right way to insert the function here to this formula?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have most often used the `hasValue()` function as follows:

```
(not hasValue({?Date}) OR {Command.Invoice Date} >= {?Date}) and
(not hasValue({?To Date}) OR {Command.Invoice Date} <= {?To Date}) and
(not hasValue({?Department}) OR {Command.SeriesName} = {?Department}) and
(not hasValue({?DOCUMENT NO}) OR {Command.DocNum} = {?DOCUMENT NO}) and
(not hasValue({?Sales Emploee}) OR {Command.SlpName} = {?Sales Emploee})
```

So either the parameter doesn't have value or the value in the column is checked against the parameter value.